# $f: A\longrightarrow B$, $I \subset A$, then $B\otimes_AA/I=B/IB$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

A ring homomorphism $f: A\longrightarrow B$ and $I$ is an ideal of $A$, then do we have $B\otimes_AA/I=B/IB$ ?

I am trying to prove that if $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a morphism between two schemes, and $Y'$ is a closed subscheme of Y, then do we have $X'=X\times_YY'$ is a closed subscheme of X?

Comment: Yes, if by $IB$ you mean the ideal in $B$ generated by $f(I)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take $B \otimes A/I \to B/IB:b \otimes [a]_I=[bf(a)]_{IB}$. It is easy to see that it is an isomorphism.